# On MouseOver change of images sometimes "flashes"

Tags: javascript, mouseover, imagemap

I use an imagemap with the following code:

```
<img name="team" src="team.jpg" width="2560" height="1600" border="0" usemap="#team" alt="" />

<map name="team">
<area shape="rect" coords="495,308,887,794" alt="" onMouseOver="document.team.src='team_a.jpg'" onMouseOut="document.team.src='team.jpg'" >
<area shape="rect" coords="1022,513,1342,897" alt="" onMouseOver="document.team.src='team_b.jpg'" onMouseOut="document.team.src='team.jpg'" >
<area shape="rect" coords="1510,480,1679,691" alt="" onMouseOver="document.team.src='team_c.jpg'" onMouseOut="document.team.src='team.jpg'" >
</map>
```

This works fine, but often the change of images "flashes".

Is there anything that can be added to the code? Should I preload the images? Are perhaps the images to big?

Comment: Preload the images and see if it still persists

Comment: possible duplicate of [mouseover element flickers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527276/mouseover-element-flickers)

Comment: I tried with preload, but the problem persists. In the meaatime I learned that this happens only with Firefox, not with Chrome, Opera, Safari or IE. I read [mouseover element flickers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527276/mouseover-element-flickers), but the solution with CSS ist not responsive.

Comment: Now it works. The flickering with Firefox must have been a cache problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to preload the images. If you are using jQuery you can count on [Lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/2007/lazy-load-images-jquery-plugin).

Anyways, there are a lot of alternatives and not only with Javascript. In this [article](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/) is pretty well explained.

Comment: Just now I realize how big the images are! definitly you need to preload.

Comment: Thank you for the link to [3 Ways to Preload Images with CSS, JavaScript, or Ajax](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/).